# How to exclude result from 2 different table and show the result?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables:

- T1 (Total User)
- T2 (User_id_that_have_done_something_for_today)

the mysql_query result from T1 are

```
(Total User)
-----
ID
-----
| 1 |
| 2 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 7 |
| 8 |
```

the mysql_query from T2 are

```
(logged)
-----
user_id_log
-----
| 1 |
| 3 |
| 4 |
| 7 |
```

How to compare T1 and T2 And only show the user that not approved?

The end result that i wanted is

```
(result)
-----
ID
-----
| 2 |
| 5 |
| 6 |
| 8 |
```

I spent 2 days to make this work but i cannot do it

I have try LEFT JOIN and NOT IT but the result is not what i wanted

Please help me, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use  `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id FROM T1 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM T2 WHERE t1.id = t2.id);
```

Comment: You done it in 3 minutes! What i can not in 2 days. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
SELECT * FROM Users u
WHERE u.id NOT IN (SELECT l.id FROM logged l)
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you to get the result .

```
select T1.ID from T1 left join T2 on T2.ID = T2.ID where T2.ID IS NULL;
```